# Get the constructor of class that inherits

Tags: php, codeigniter, inheritance

I have this class in /libraries.

```
class CI_Decorator extends CI_Controller {


    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

The error I get is very weird:

```
Message: Undefined property: CI_Decorator::$load
Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php
Backtrace:
File: /application/libraries/CI_Decorator.php
```

And is because I try to get CI_Controller constructor with

```
parent::__construct();
```

UPDATE:

I am trying to implement this [Decorator](https://github.com/ccschmitz/codeigniter-decorator) but I think was developed for an earlier version of CI.

Comment: I think `parent::__construct();` is not the issue here. `Undefined property: CI_Decorator::$load` this message is telling you that `libaries/Form_validation.php` is not found or something like that. Or your `$load` property must me doing something unusual.

Comment: what is `CI_Decorator` ? you cant call controller inside another controller

Comment: Please check my update in question.

Answer (score 1):

Change the file name to Decorator.php and in the class file use this.

```
class Decorator{
  //there is no parent so you cannot call a parent constructor
  //public function __construct() {
      //parent::__construct();
  //}

}
```

Only preface a file (or class) name with "CI_" when you wish to replace one of CodeIgniter's core classes. If a core class with that name does not exist the load will fail.

If you want to extend a native class then you will preface the class and file name with `MY_` or with the prefix you set in config.php

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'YOURPREFIX_';
```

Extending CI_Controller more than once is frustrating too and you will run into a different but related problem. You will find many answers to that question here on Stack Overflow. In the search box above use the search term "[codeigniter] extending CI_controller" (without the quote marks)